# React.JS: Issue With Creating Table Headers Programatically

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

I'm pretty new to React and am having issues rendering the headings of a table programatically: Basically I want each heading to be from an array. I am creating the array in the constructor, and referencing it later. For now I just want to get headings to worker, but later I would like to set each cell with a value from an array. What I have so far is this:

```
import React from "react";
import firebase from "../firestore";

const db = firebase.firestore();
const docRef = db.collection("tournaments").doc("Siege");


class Table extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
              matches: [],
              headers:[],
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        let headers =["Time"];
        let matches = docRef.collection("Matches").get().then(querySnapshot => {
            matches = querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data());
            this.setState( {matches});
            docRef.get().then(snapshot=> {
                var noPitches=snapshot.data().numberPitches;
                for (let i=1; i<noPitches; i++){
                    headers.push("Pitch " + i);
                }
            });
            this.setState({headers});
        });
    }





    render() {

        return (

            <div>
                <table id='mytable'>
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        { this.state.headers.map((header,index) =>
                        <th key={index}>{header} </th>
                        )}
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                </table>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default Table;
```

When The table is rendered, I can only see the first heading, time. When outputting the headings array to the console I can see, it actually does the log three times. The first two times, both headers and this.state.headers are empty, the third time it logs the right value. I'm really confused as to what is happening and any help would be appreciated.

[image: Web Console]
[image: Table Ouput]

Comment: The constructor is not a place to update the state, you should do that in componentDidMount. And you should not use a for loop to generate jsx, you should use map instead like this:  this.state.headers.map((header,index) => { return <th key={index} ...}

Comment: I've updated so that state is set in ComponentDidMount. I'm struggling with the mapping, so far I have this:

 generateHeader(){
        this.state.headers.map((header,index) =>
            
            <th key = {index}>{header} </th>
        );
    }

But I can't figure out how to return <th>without breaking it

Comment: You can do the headers.map directly inside the render/return of your component, no need to create a function for that

Comment: Inside your render/return you can do:  {this.state.headers.map((header, index) => ...  }

Comment: Okay I think I have that working for me now, I've updated my code to reflect it. However, it is still showing only time as a heading, ie the first object in the array.

Comment: then for (let i=1; i<noPitches; i++){
                    headers.push("Pitch " + i);
                }
is not iterating i.e. not pushing anything into that array. Be sure you are connecting well to the collection and the collection has the data you are trying to show there. 

BTW something smells bad to me in the way you are accessing  data docRef.get().then(snapshot=> {
                var noPitches=snapshot.data().numberPitches;

You should be able to retrieve your numberPitches and your matches in the same call if its the same collection reference.

Comment: You were right, I had my loops set up to update the state at the wrong time. Thank You!